# Php block access without redirected .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

With htaccess im redirecting:

```
RewriteRule ^secure/ login.php  [NC,L]
```

I only want people to be allowed to visit: `website.com/secure/`
But not: `website.com/login.php`

Anyone got an idea how to do this? Possibly in php?

Comment: `!^/secure`, then, so hits that AREN'T on /secure get redirected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

# block direct access to /login.php
# RewriteRule ^ - [F] line sends status 403 when RewriteCond succeeds.    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /login\.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# internally rewrite /secure to /login.php
RewriteRule ^secure/?$ login.php [NC,L]
```

First rule is using `THE_REQUEST` variable. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it **doesn't get overwritten** after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: RewriteRule ^ - [F]

Comment: I have added more details in answer.